# WFFM error on a form page

Tags: wffm

When I'm opening one form of my build that runs with WFFM this is the error I get:

**Could not find configuration node: wffm/modelFactory**

anyone know what this error is all about? where is this configuration set?
thanks

UPDATE: Sitecore 8.0 rev 160115

WFFM: 8.0 151127

Comment: Could you include the version of WFFM & Sitecore?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.config (in include) should have a wffm/modelFactory node

Comment: well this was upgraded from sitecore 8.0 update 3 to 7 and upgraded WFFM update 4 and 6. and one of the steps was to have Sitecore.Forms.MVC as disabled if I'm not mistaken. Only the sitecore.forms should be enabled

Comment: I don't have your exact same version - I just found the node in an older 8.0 with wffm. I know the node is gone in 8.1 but I don't have any versions in between at my disposal right now.

Comment: You could verify with the files from a clean install - always best in such a situation

Comment: If you are sure that you followed the update steps correctly, open up your website's bin folder and look at the properties for each of the `Sitecore.Forms.*` and `Sitecore.WFFM.*` DLLs and check their version numbers. They should all be 8.0.151127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the default config for [that version of WFFMs](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Web_Forms_For_Marketers/Web_Forms_for_Marketers_80/Web_Forms_for_Marketers_80_Update_6.aspx) that node is not in the config (the wffm node is there but I can't see the modelFactory).

As Gatogordo suggests this node exists in previous versions of WFFMs:

```
<wffm>
  <formProcessors>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Processors.SitecoreFormProcessor, Sitecore.Forms.Mvc"/>
  </formProcessors>

  <modelFactory type="Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Data.ModelFactory, Sitecore.Forms.Mvc" singleInstance="true">
    <param name="renderingContext" ref="wffm/renderingContext"/>
  </modelFactory>

  <renderingContext type="Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Data.Wrappers.WrappedRenderingContext, Sitecore.Forms.Mvc" singleInstance="true"/>

  <formDataManager type="Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Data.FormDataManager, Sitecore.Forms.Mvc" singleInstance="true">
    <param name="processorFactory" ref="wffm/formProcessorsFactory"/>
  </formDataManager>

  <formProcessorsFactory type="Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Data.SitecoreProcessorFactory, Sitecore.Forms.Mvc" singleInstance="true"/>
</wffm>
```

So either your DLLs are old and expecting old config - or the installer is wrong and this config needs to be present in Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.config

I would redownload the installation package from the link above, unpack it and compare the DLL versions against your bin folder, also look for extra DLLs perhaps. If they all look correct, try adding that config node back in and see if it works.

Be worth logging this with Sitecore as well if the config on the installation package is incorrect.